# how to create a box at the bottom right of my application that runs the android camera

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview, android-canvas, image

So, I have an application that uses a canvas and animated a moving block. What I would ultimately like to do is have the camera running capturing the user's face without showing the camera screen on the app or have a box at the bottom right of my screen that showing what the camera sees.

Is it possible to have a mini screen at the bottom right of my app that is displaying the camera or does the camera have to take the full screen?

Or if it is possible just to quickly snap a picture and display a bitmap without losing my application, that would be fine also.

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a mini screen at the bottom right of my app that is displaying the camera or does the camera have to take the full screen?

It is possible, [See the 1st Screenshot here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qiktmobile.android). Theirs is in top left instead of bottom right, but it should work just the same. In this Qik application the full screen shows the other person you are talking with, and the small box shows the live view from your camera.

I wouldn't know how they did that, but I imagine if you follow along with [Building a Camera App](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) in the docs it would get you most the way there. You just need to adjust the size of the preview canvas, and figure out how to use the front camera instead of back.